# Adding objects to existing JSON file

Tags: node.js, json

The goal of this node.js code is to be able to read, add and delete JSON objects. My JSON code looks like this:

```
{
    "first": [
    {
        "id": 1112313,
        "price": 11     
    },
    {
        "id": 11123122413,
        "price": 112    
    }
    ],
    "second": [
    {
        "id": 4121312,
        "price": 55 
    }
    ],
    "third": [
    {
        "id": 87845,
        "price": 444    
    }
    ]
}
```

The reading part I figured out, but the deleting and adding new objects part doesn't work for me. I only get [Object Object] written in my JSON file. So far my code looks like this:

```
//Reading JSON file
var fs = require('fs');
var object = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./jsonFile.JSON', 'utf8'));
console.log(object.first[0].price);

//Deleting 
delete object.first[0].price

//Adding a new object
object.first[] = {"id":11245, "price": 123};

//Writing results to JSON file
fs.writeFileSync('jsonFile.json', object);
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync('jsonFile.json', JSON.stringify( object, null, 2 ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
//Reading JSON file
var fs = require('fs');
var object = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./jsonFile.JSON', 'utf8'));
console.log(object.first[0].price);

//Deleting 
delete object.first[0].price

//Adding a new object
object.first = [{ id: 11245, price: 123 }];

//Writing results to JSON file
fs.writeFileSync('jsonFile.json', JSON.stringify(object));
```

The `JSON.stringify` is important because you'll get the dreaded `[object Object]` otherwise.

Also note how `object.first` has been set to a new array here.

Comment: Hmm yeah that works, one thing though, the delete part seems to wipe the entire first object. Any way to just wipe one and leave the other intact?

Comment: Yep, like this: `delete object.first[0]["price"]` - note how you use the square bracket notation here. You can also do the reverse when adding: `object.first[0]["price"] = 123`

Comment: Well, sort of the reverse anyway.

Comment: Oh and I'm left with {"first":[null,{"id":11123122413,"price":112},{"i... the nasty null. Easy way to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you definitely using `delete object.first[0]["price"]` and not just `delete object.first[0]`?

Comment: Works fine now :D